# Getting a spinner's item list

Tags: android, android-spinner

I can retrieve a list of all items of a spinner by:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i =0; i<spinner.getCount(); ++i)
{
    String item = String.valueOf(spinner.getItemAtPosition(i));
    list.add(item);
}
```

Or storing the item list globally...

Is there any more elegant way, something like *.getItemList()*?

My concern is the iteration (linear complexity), I would prefer to directly get the list from the adapter (possibly constant complexity?)

Comment: Develop a custom adapter with the desired method.

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html (which inherits from Adapter)

You will find that the method you're looking for doesn't exist

Your solution is about as elegant as it gets

Comment: how is this different to what I wrote? My concern is the iteration (linear complexity), I would prefer to directly get the list from the adapter (possibly constant complexity)

Comment: Its not really, I somehow managed to not see that part of your question. See my edit